# How to make a JPG files DCF compatible? (command line)

Tags: metadata, batch, exiftool, linux

At the moment I use Sony’s [Imaging Edge Desktop](https://imagingedge.sony.net/en-us/ie-desktop.html) to make
individual photos viewable in camera. However, this is cumbersome if
there are many pictures.

*How can it be done from the command line?*

According to the thread [Make JPEG file DCF compatible](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=2228.0) in the
ExifTool Forum it’s possible with ExifTool, but so far I haven’t
succeeded. I tried copying EXIF data from an image taken with my
camera (Ricoh GR III):

```
exiftool -TagsFromFile R0000001.JPG -all:all -unsafe -XML:All R0000007.JPG
```

Comment: `...but so far I haven’t succeeded.` Glad to see that you've tried already. Could you please share what commands/scripts/methods you used so far and what their (non-successful) outcome was?
Also, what's the final goal of uploading photos *to* your camera?

Comment: I basically tried copying all EXIF data from an image that I took with the camera. The goal is to view pictures on the camera that come from elsewhere. It works, just with that Sony tool, I think there is no batch option.

Comment: How did you try copying all EXIF data? Feel free to rewrite your question and include the command that you used for that. I understand that you want to view the pictures on camera, but is that really the end-goal? I suspect you want to view them on camera for a certain purpose. If you can include that purpose in your question, there might be other methods to achieve the same end-goal.

Comment: The end-goal is to view pictures in the camera.

Comment: Why not view them on your phone, tablet, or any other screen device? 
Is it possible to extract all EXIF tags from an image, then run it through Sony's software, extract all EXIF tags again and do a diff to see what changed?

Comment: Did you delete any `JFIF` blocks as per that thread?  You would add `-JFIF:ALL=` to your command.

Comment: @StarGeek Thanks, that worked but only in conjunction with chaning chroma subsampling with ImageMagick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, with lots of help on the Internet, including the [suggestion](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/118119/how-to-make-a-jpg-files-dcf-compatible-command-line#comment228002_118119) by @StarGeek, I got it to work. The required tools are:

- [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/)
- [ImageMagick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick)

You also need a photo taken with the camera, here:

```
R0000349.JPG
```

For testing, if you don't have an existing image, create one (can be any aspect ratio):

```
convert -size 2000x1000 radial-gradient:red-blue TEST.JPG
```

Then convert that image:

```
INPUT=TEST.JPG
OUTPUT=A0000001.JPG # DCF compatible
THUMBNAIL=THUMB.JPG
ORIGINAL=R0000349.JPG # taken with the camera
convert -sampling-factor 4:2:2 $INPUT $OUTPUT
exiftool -TagsFromFile $ORIGINAL -all:all -unsafe -XML:All -JFIF:ALL= $OUTPUT
convert $INPUT -resize 160x120 -background black -gravity center -extent 160x120 -sampling-factor 4:2:2 $THUMBNAIL
exiftool "-ThumbnailImage<=$THUMBNAIL" $OUTPUT
```

To set the orientation of the image, add another step:

```
ORIENTATION=1 # 1 = 0°, 3 = 180°, 6 = 90°, 8 = -90°
exiftool -Orientation=$ORIENTATION -n $OUTPUT
```

Finally, put `$OUTPUT` into a [DCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_rule_for_Camera_File_system) compatible path on your camera.

Make sure that the number in the file name is unique on the card, or else the camera may be confused. For example, if there is `A0000001.JPG` and `B0000001.JPG` on the card, then my Ricoh GR III displays neither of the images.